# apt-get install of zookeeper-server throws error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-zookeeper, apt

I am trying to install zookeeper and zookeeper-server on my ubuntu machine, these are the steps i did :-

1. added the key

   curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
2. I added the following linesto my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.key

   deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh trusty-cdh5.8 contrib

   deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/cdh trusty-cdh5.8 contrib
3. I did a apt-get update

   apt-get update
4. I then install zookeeper

   apt-get install zookeeper

Note the line :-
     Setting up zookeeper (3.4.8-1) ...

5. I install zookeeper-server

   apt-get install zookeeper-server

And i get the following error :-

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zookeeper-server : Depends: zookeeper (= 3.4.5+cdh5.8.5+98-1.cdh5.8.5.p0.10~trusty-cdh5.8.5) but 3.4.8-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I am aware of the wrong version dependency, but I am not sure how to fix this error. Is the repository itself broken, Am I supposed to get the different version from different repositories?

Please kindly advice, Thanks

Comment: You need to install the same version of zookeeper-server.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution on cloudera's website on the installation steps

[https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#topic_4_4_1__p_44][1]

Apparently there are additional steps you need to follow for Ubuntu Trusty and Debian Jessie

> This step ensures that you get the right ZooKeeper package for the
>   current CDH release. You need to prioritize the Cloudera repository
>   you have just added, such that you install the CDH version of
>   ZooKeeper rather than the version that is bundled with Ubuntu Trusty
>   or Debian Jessie.

To do this, you need to create a file called /etc/apt/preferences.d/cloudera.pref

and add the following lines :-

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Cloudera, l=Cloudera
Pin-Priority: 501
```